# Canon MP237 can print but CANNOT scan

Tags: 14.04, printing, canon, scanning, ip-scanner

I have this Cannon MP237 (3-in-1) printer and I can print properly using the software on Ubuntu 14.04.  However, I cannot scan with it.  I even tried GIMP Image Editor but I still cannot do any scanning.  The copy function of the printer works well so I'm sure it's a software issue.  Please advise, thanks.

Comment: In Linux,  printing and scanning are two separate tasks.  Printing is handled through CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) and scanning is handled by "SANE" (Scanner Access Now Easy) Read `man sane`, and thinnk. about device ownership/permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not own/use this printer, but from a quick search on the internet, I found that Canon provides a scanner driver named [MP230 series ScanGear MP Ver. 2.00 for Linux (for 64-bit versions)](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer/products/printers/pixma/mp-series/pixma-mp230.html?type=drivers&detailId=tcm%3A13-994553&os=Linux+(64-bit)&language=en) for this printer on its website.

Also, I found [a fairly helpful installation article about this same printer](https://web.archive.org/web/20141026214043/http://www.distroubuntu.com/2013/01/install-printer-canon-pixma-mp-237-di.html) (albeit in a different language - You can use Google Translate to view this in your preferred language).

Hope this helps.